# Drop privileges as regular non-root user for sandboxing?

Tags: c, linux, security, sandbox, privileges

Is it possible to use a set of C library or system calls to drop all user privileges on POSIX, or at least on Linux?  Note that I am not asking how to drop `root` privileges, which is what all of the other StackOverflow search results seem to be asking and answering.

I want the same effect as switching to user `nobody`, but stronger if possible.  That is, I want my C application to do the following:

- Run as a normal user, *not* `root`, and without the setuid file permission bit
- Retain the ability to access specific files and open outgoing network connections
- Voluntarily and permanently lose the ability to read and write files in specified (or all) directories, especially `$HOME`
- If possible, give up or sandbox all other nonessential abilities, like opening a listening socket with `accept`

---

Things I have considered so far that don't fit the bill:

- Switching to user `nobody` with `setuid`/`setgid`

  - Ordinary users are forbidden from switching to other users (like `nobody`), and the application should not require `root` just to switch to `nobody`.
- [Linux/POSIX.1e Capabilities](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man7/capabilities.7.html)

  - Capabilities only add `root`-like privileges, not take away ordinary user privileges
- Traditional [seccomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp)

  - My application will need more than just `exit`, `sigreturn`, `read`, and `write`

Things that look interesting, but for which I couldn't find documentation, appear to be unmaintained, or appear to be non-portable:

- [seccomp-bpf](https://lwn.net/Articles/475043/)
- [AppArmor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor)
- [grsecurity RBAC/role-based access control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grsecurity#Role-based_access_control)

---

So is there a well-documented, preferably portable way to drop nonessential user privileges and sandbox a process without having to become `root` first?

Comment: Have you considered something like cgroups/namespaces?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @self Strongly disagree. This is a well researched question with a good description and a list of things which are close, but not really fitting the solution. It's actually one of the best written questions I saw on SO in a long time.

Comment: The problem is this question is vulnerable to discussion.

Comment: For future developers stumbling onto this question, OpenBSD has a recent proposal for a [`tame` system call](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-tech&m=143725996614627&w=2) that does exactly what I was looking for.  Hopefully it gets merged and, eventually, a cross-platform API emerges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely any solution will work on all POSIX, since POSIX doesn't define the mechanism you're looking for.

Looking at just the requirements and just Linux, probably the easiest way to satisfy them is actual via the security modules. Any of apparmor, selinux, RBAC will do what you need, but only via external profile - not something built into your app. The problem may be that adding a profile in all those cases requires the root user to do it (but the profile applies to user process too).

A bit more complicated solution that almost satisfies the requirements is seccomp. While it doesn't understand paths at all (you can only see pointers), there are ways to limit the access: seccomp policies can be defined per thread, so you could redesign your system to have a "path verification thread", which doesn't do anything apart from reading paths and returning sockets if they match your specification. Then limit that thread to just `recv()`, `open()` and `send()`. Thread doing other work can then drop `open()` and use the other service.

Or if you can configure the paths at program startup, you can put them into an array, mark that page as read-only, and setup seccomp policy which will only accept `open()` with filenames from that array (that's just a pointer comparison in that case).

To some extent, the approach of splitting application into separate processes which have very limited responsibilities is something you could replicate on other systems, but without the same guarantees as on Linux. For example qmail is kind of a system of very small processes which work as a pipeline for data (simplification). On Linux you could still apply seccomp to them, on Solaris just drop `exec` and other capabilities, on other systems... I don't know, but probably you can do something.